# Reading options in middleware in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How do I read the options in my middleware that i defined in `ConfigureService` in Startup?
I assume that defining the type for `myOptions` is all I have to do.

Like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMyMiddleware(myOptions =>
    {
        myOptions.MyProperty= "hello";
    });
}
```

The options are configured in `AddMyMiddleware` by doing:

```
services.Configure(setupAction);
```

This is currently for beta8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the options into the `Invoke` method of the middleware:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IOptions<TOptions> optionsAccessor)
{
   // use optionsAccessor.Value..
}
```

Where `TOptions` is the type of the configured options.